# сравнение доверительных интервалов

Tags: математика, статистика

#### Задача из области мат. статистики

имеется 2 интервала:

1. первый: [4.2:5.6] (mean 4.9, n = 23);
2. второй: [4.7, 5.5] (mean 5.1, n = 74)

Как видите, один находится внутри другого, как сравнить эти показатели и доказать, что второй действительно больше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интервалы не могут быть "один больше другого". Интервалы могут перекрыватсья. И не важно, как именно они перекрываются. Если у них есть пересечение, это означает, что статистически значимого отличия в полученных оценках параметра нет. (Точнее говоря, нулевая гипотеза о согласованности выборок не может быть отклонена). В вашем случае нельзя утверждать, что mean 5.1 больше mean 4.9, по крайней мере, на ваших выборках и при вашем выбраном уровне достоверности. (Который вы почему-то даже не упомянули).

Comment: уровень достоверности 95%. Я правильно понял, что на этом уровне достоверности нельзя точно сказать, какая величина больше, а какая меньше? Есть другие инструменты для доказательства?

Comment: Да, вы поняли правильно. Здесь дело не в инструментах, а в выборках. Сужение широты доверительного интервала могут привести, к тому, что интервалы перестанут пересекаться.  Например  -  за счет увеличения количества элементов в выборках. Или увеличения уровня достоверности. Но только в вашем случае это врят-ли сработает. Ну, разве что вы увеличите количество элементов в выборке раз в 100.